# Session persistence on Azure load balancer based on cookies

Tags: azure, azure-load-balancer

Is it possible to do session persistence on Azure load balancers based on cookies, I know you can do it on Client IP but wondered about cookies?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Azure Load Balancer doesn't support cookie based affinity. In order to achieve that you need to use Azure Application Gateway:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/how-to-troubleshoot-application-gateway-session-affinity-issues